# Single line ends preserved in markdown output?

Tags: markdown, line-endings

I'm editing markdown files in an online markdown editor, copying them from a file opened in Notepad++, and copying them back to Notepad++ to save when I'm done. The problem: every line end in a text file creates a line end in the markdown editor's composed output. I understand that single line ends in markdown are supposed to be ignored (apart from special cases like code blocks).

This is a problem because my organization requires text files, including markdown files, to observe a maximum line length of 80 characters. We've got filters that scan for this, when files are committed to Git for example, and flag overlength lines as errors.

If the markdown composer doesn't ignore line ends, I must write every paragraph of text as a single line, making it impossible to observe the 80-character length limit.

By now you're probably seething because I haven't said *which* online markdown editor I'm using. I haven't said because it doesn't seem to matter. I've tried three completely different ones, and they all do this. The one I ended up using is https://stackedit.io/app#.

I thought this might be happening because Notepad++ stores each line end as <CR><LF> and the markdown editors interpret that as *two* line ends. I tried setting Notepad++ to use Linux line ends instead, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on which implementation you are using.

Preserving line endings (or treating soft line breaks as hard line breaks) is an add-on which was first popularized by GitHub Flavored Markdown has since become very common in web based Markdown editors. Native text editors have tools for hard wrapping lines, but those tools don't usually exist in web forms. Most users will type long continuous lines in a web form. If the user adds a soft line break, then it can reasonably be assumed that the user intended a line break to exist there. Therefore, in your browser, you will find most implementations will include the soft-to-hard line break extension by default.

In the past, GitHub Flavored Markdown was documented in GitHub's help pages and the fact that line endings were preserved was clearly documented. However, since they switched to an extended Commonmark implementation, it is no longer so clear. In their spec they do not list an extension for line breaks, which suggests they follow typical Commonmark behavior. However, the Commonmark spec is very unclear regarding [soft line breaks](https://github.github.com/gfm/#soft-line-breaks):

> A conforming parser may render a soft line break in HTML either as a
>   line break or as a space.
>
> A renderer may also provide an option to render soft line breaks as
>   hard line breaks.

Therefore, if you are using a Commonmark based implementation, it is very relevant to know which implementation you are using. Some may use a different default than others and some may provide a different way of changing that default.

However, if you are using an implementation which is based in the original rules at daringfireball.com, then you probably can be confident that hard line breaks are always hard and soft line breaks are ignored.

If, however, you are using an implementation from each camp, it can be very confusing and frustrating trying to get the two to work together.

Comment: Thank you, that's pretty clear and informative. Not what I hoped to hear, though. It sounds like I'll have better luck with a local editor/formatter.